# VBS: Merge files with almost equal names

Tags: file, vbscript, merge, text-files

I have hundreds of files within folders with almost equal names like *1560q90j-a.txt* and *1560q90j-b.txt*. Those files are temporarely (random) generated.
How can I merge those files within a given folder, who have the same nine characters at the beginning, followed by one different to a new one. Also deleting the source files:

```
 Commandline: copy 1560q90j-a.txt+1560q90j-b.txt 1560q90j.txt
 Commandline: del 1560q90j-?.txt
 Commandline: copy atiy09hr-a.txt+atiy09hr-a.txt atiy09hr.txt
 Commandline: del atiy09hr-?.txt
```

And later I will merge all new files to only one file with one blank line as seperator between the file content:

```
 Commandline: copy 560q90j.txt+blankline.txt+atiy09hr.txt+blankline.txt+ ... Allfile.txt
```

Perhaps somebody is able to help me with a script in VBS to fulfil my wishes.

Thanks! Mitch

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForAppending = 8
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

objStartFolder = "C:\temp\test\" 'the folder where your text files are

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
        Set writefile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\" & Left(objFile.Name, 8) & ".txt", ForAppending, True)'open output file based on first 8 letters of found file
        set readfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objStartFolder & objFile.Name, ForReading, False) 'open found file
        contents = readfile.ReadAll  'read its content
        writefile.WriteLine(contents)  'append to output file
        readfile.close  'close file
        writefile.Close()
        objFSO.DeleteFile(objStartFolder & objFile.Name) 'delete file
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, It works great for the frist part.
And for the second part I take this script:

    `Const ForReading = 1
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objOutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("output.txt") ' in CurrenDirectory
    strComputer = "." ' This Computer
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set FileList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Directory.Name='C:\Temp'} Where " _
      & "ResultClass = CIM_DataFile")
    For Each objFile In FileList
        Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFile.Name, ForReading) 
        strText = objTextFile.ReadAll
        objTextFile.Close
        objOutputFile.WriteLine strText & vbcrlf
    Next
    objOutputFile.Close`

Thanks again and *Valentine's Greetings*